# how can a qt based http server read the pending data from a jquery http post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, qt

EDIT: I've managed to get it working. Apparently it is an issue with Chromium. The solution would be to use $.post({...}) instead of $.ajax({...}). No idea as to why it works, but as long as it does, I'm happy.

how can I send a string using javascript to my local http server?
My browser is running the following javascript codechunk:

```
$.ajax({                                                              
                type : "post",                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",                                                                                                                                                                                      
                dataType : "string",                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                url : "h@#p://127.0.0.1:8080",                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                data : "test",                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                success : alert("success"),                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            });
```

In the end only the header can be read, whereas the 'data' string remains in "pending" status (chromium->inspect_element->Network) and never reaches the server.
I'm currently trying to wait/check for other incoming/pending connections, but the server
does not seem to take them into account.

```
while(hasPendingConnections())                                                                                                                                                                                                 
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    QTcpSocket * sock = nextPendingConnection();                                                                                                                                                                           
    if (sock->canReadLine())                                                                                                                                                                                           
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        QString str = QString(sock->readLine());                                                                                                                                                               
        qDebug() << str;                                                                                                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
}
```

this is what the server receives via QTcpSocket, when the browser makes the ajax call:

```
"POST / HTTP/1.1
"
"Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
"
"Connection: keep-alive
"
"Content-Length: 4
"
"Accept: */*
"
"Origin: h@#p://127.0.0.1:8080
"
"X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
"
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.102 Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36
"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
"
"Referer: h@#p://127.0.0.1:8080/
"
"Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
"
"Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ja;q=0.6,de;q=0.4,pl;q=0.2
```

Now, how do I get that data component/string?

Cheers /banpei